# logged_in_user not working bypassing landing page for logged in users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've seen a few similar posts about this but they didn't seem to resolve my problem.

**Problem**
It simply doesn't work. Doesn't error out, nothing, just doesn't evaluate and I don't know why because it does for other things?

Here is my Welcome controller definition:

```
  def show
    if logged_in?
      # raise  #I raise an error here and nothing happens on the web page. Just to confirm this isn't working for my sanity. 
      redirect_to recipes_url
    else
      render template: "welcome/#{params[:welcome]}"
    end
  end
```

The function logged_in? is defined in my /helpers/sessions_helper.rb:

```
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
```

Here is the current_user:

```
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
    #  raise #The test still pass, so this branch is currently untested.
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
```

And my routes are:

```
 get 'welcome/:welcome' => 'welcome#show'
 root :to => 'welcome#home'
```

Why doesn't this work? It just stays on the welcome page regardless of if I'm logged in or not. I know that logged_in? is evaluating correctly because I have other links on the page that are dynamic based upon this.

**EDIT:**  What's really weird is that the logged_in? works in my view just not in this controller.

Here's a snippet from the nav of in the application layout view.

```
  <% if logged_in? %>
      <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %></li>
    <% else %>
      <li><%= link_to "Browse recipes", recipes_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
    <% end %>
```

[Picture of the resulting site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx8Sa.png)

Comment: r u using devise ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. The logged_in method was working fine. The reason that this wasn't working was because my route was going directly to the view 'welcome#home' and bypassing the controller altogether.

As soon as I made the route 'welcome#show' I was able to get this to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`logged_in_user` isn't actually doing or returning anything if the user is already signed in. It just returns nil which evaluates to false, so there's no way for your `show` action to even reach the `redirect_to recipes_url` statement.

Did you intend to use the `logged_in?` function? This should work, provided `logged_in?` does what its name implies:

```
   def show
    if logged_in?
      redirect_to recipes_url
    else
      render template: "welcome/#{params[:welcome]}"
    end
  end
```

If using devise, make sure you're using a model named `User`, have devise defined in your `routes.rb` with `devise_for :users` and have devise declared on your model with at least the following:

```
 devise :database_authenticatable,
         :registerable,
         :rememberable,
         :validatable
```

Comment: I edited my original question. Thanks! You're definitely right about using logged_in however this still isn't working for me? Still not sure why...

Comment: Where/how is `logged_in?` defined?

Comment: See above. I edited the post. It's defined in the helpers/session_helpers.rb file as !current_user.nil?

Comment: Are you using devise? Try `current_user.present?`

Comment: No, it's my first Ruby app so I went through the Hartl tutorial: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out

Comment: Are you setting the session properly and retrieving current_user from the session. What's your method for `current_user`?

Comment: Are you sure `user_id` is defined?

Comment: OK. I think I have more information. The controller "show" isn't firing at all. I put a raise exception as the first line, and the page still renders fine. Why would the controller show action not be firing at all to render welcome#home